# How to set a struct in from one package, then use it it's original package

Tags: go, struct, package

I am trying to send a struct that is set in one package to the original package, but i can't get it to work. This is somewhat what i want.

main.go

```
package main

import (    
    router "router"
)

func main() {
    cfg := router.Config{
        some = true
    }

    router.Sending(cfg)
}
```

router.go

```
package router

import (
    "log"
)

type Config struct {
    some bool
}

func Sending(class Config){ 
    if Config.some{
        log.Println("it worked")
    }
}
```

Comment: Lower-case field names are package-private. Use `Some bool` instead of `some bool`. Also fix your syntax: `cfg := &router.Config{Some: true}`

Comment: There’s no reason to make `cfg` a pointer as the parameter to Sending is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Syntaxt errors it is.

I read some other question answer incorrectly, and of course it is not

```
func Sending(class Config){ 
    if Config.some{
        log.Println("it worked")
    }
}
```

it is

```
func Sending(class Config){ 
    if class.some{
        log.Println("it worked")
    }
}
```

And of course,

```
type Config struct {
    Some bool
}
```

and not

```
type Config struct {
    some bool
}
```

as Zyl mentioned